# Laravel4 Iframe URL with special chartecter throw NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently using Laravel4 for my project.

It's ok when I use this:

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to('/'). $video->path}}" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

But when I use this:

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to('/'). $video->path}}&autoplay=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

The iframe will return Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException.

How can I fix this? Please help me out.
Thanks so much smile

Answer (score 1):

I think you doing the query string wrong.

If the URL of the video is: yoursite.com/video1 and you append a &autoplay=0, then the url will be yoursite.com/video1&autoplay=0 which does not exist.

Change the &autoplay=0 to ?autoplay=0 to see if its works.